# Vagrant - Why provisioning a box when I can create a new one

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

I'm relatively new to Vagrant and I understood provisioning is used to install automatically new software on the guest machine.
Now, what I don't understand, if I need to install new software every time I destroy and re-up my machine, I think it's better to create a new box after I finished to set-up my original box.

Maybe the provisioning is great if I need to alter configurations every time I boot the machine, but again, wouldn't it be better have a box already updated?

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily, so lets take this example (this is  my real case)

I work with vagrant to setup customer-like instance, I do some Java development. I use from the same box (I have 2 boxes, ubuntu and centos only with OS) for my projects and will do the provisioning based on my customer setup (app server, db mainly)

so lets take 2 examples:

1. Customer 1:
   I use centos base box and will provision Tomcat + postgresql - The provisioning happens only once (unless a destroy is needed but generally once I have imported db and all I will use the same VM for the project time)
2. Customer 2:
   I use centos base box but this time will provision Jetty and mysql.

Does it worth to create 2 boxes with those software installed ? in my opinion no.

The reason why I would install software on VM and repackage as base box is when the provisioning takes quite some time (hours) and I need to destroy/provision a lot, but in my case this is happens quite rarely. I will do the provisioning once (maybe I need to tweak a bit so will destroy and recreate VM) but then when its final, I will not destroy so does not make sense to create base box with all software packaged inside